# Printing Exception vs Exception.getMessage

Tags: java, exception

Is there a best practice on using the followng two pieces of code regarding exceptions.

```
//code1

} catch (SomeException e) {
    logger.error("Noinstance available!", e.getMessage());
}

//code2
} catch (SomeException e) {
    logger.error("Noinstance available!", e);
}
```

When should I use the getMessage method of an exception?

Comment: Almost all the time. Unless you know the SomeException and the overriden toString method. The e.getMessage() is the standard way

Comment: If you only log the message, you don't get a stack trace, or the nested exception should there be one. Log the exception...

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper: "Almost all the time" what? The first? I prefer not to lose the information about where the exception came from, its cause etc.

Comment: You should *always* log the whole exception, not just the message. Otherwise the logging framework can't give you the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Here is my theory, If SomeException is a specific  exception (which I think it is meant) then there is no point is keeping the full information where the exception was caught,( the log framework knows where , and off course has to be defined in the pattern ) , For example If I am catching (FileNotFoundException ) , then I know it is fileNotFoundException and printing the whole stack would is just extra information I would not care. Thus e.getMessage() is good  enough. Now Having IOException or Exception, then I would have to know what exactly caused it.@JonSkeet what do you say ?

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper If `SomeException` is caused by `FooException` which is caused by `BarException` which is caused by `FileNotFoundException` that is valuable information that you want. Almost all of the time you do not want to throw away information.

Comment: Agreed, better to have more info than depending on e.getmessage where chances are it can be blank

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The first doesn't compile because the method `error` accept a `String` as first parameter and a `Throwable` as second parameter.

`e.getMessage()` is not a `Throwable`.

The code should be

```
} catch (SomeException e) {
    // No stack trace
    logger.error("Noinstance available! " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Compared with

```
} catch (SomeException e) {
    // Prints message and stack trace
    logger.error("Noinstance available!", e);
}
```

The first prints only a message. The second prints also the whole stack trace.

It depends from the context if it is necessary to print the stack trace or not.

If you already know why an exception can be thrown it is not a good idea to print the whole stack trace.

If you don't know, it is better to print the whole strack trace to find easily the error.

Comment: I am using sl4j logger and my code1 compiles. why is that

Comment: Ok, my info was for standard log4j, but the rest remains valid

Comment: Because sl4j has overloaded methods like `.error(String...)` `.error(String..., Throwable)`, and `.error(Throwable)`.  Best practices with sl4j, the info above, and the desire to see the stack trace is `LOG.error("Something went wrong: {}", e);`  This will turn whole stack trace into a string, and use only 1 log entry.  Very important if you are using MDC logging. Without the `{}` each `caused by` would be another log entry, without MDC stuff.

Answer (score 3):

This prototype is useful, when you classify exception into **Business level** and **Technical exception**.

For Business level exception, you just use the message, by logging for  **analytics** or may be to display on the screen a meaning information (something didnt work).

For Technical exception, its better to log the error with stacktrace, to find of out the issue and it is easy to debug and resolve.

Answer (score 2):

With stacktrace:

```
logger.error("Could not do XYZ because of: " + ex, ex);
```

Without stacktrace:

```
logger.error("Could not do XYZ because of: " + ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you need stack trace of original exception (SomeException). If yes, then code2 is correct option here. Note that is more common way of handling these situations.

If you are not interested in what was the original exception, you can use code1 but this one is not correct. Because the code you sent takes message as argument. So the correct way is:

```
logger.error("Noinstance available! - reason:" + e.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
```

It Returns the detail message string of this throwable.

```
logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
```

Creates a localized description of this throwable. Subclasses may override this method in order to produce a locale-specific message. For subclasses that do not override this method, the default implementation returns the same result as getMessage().

In your case e is nothing but the object of exception ...

getLocalizedMessage() u need to override and give your own message i.e the meaning for localized message.

Answer (score 0):

`Exception.printStackTrace()` should not be used unless youre for example debugging.

For logging, it is definetly better to use `Exception.getMessage()`. Also please notice that many logging frameworks (for example Log4j) accepts exception it self as an argument on logging method (for example `error()`) and works it out by itself.